# Cobol REPLACING ALL pattern matching

Tags: cobol

I'm working on converting some legacy COBOL code and came across a statement like this:

```
INSPECT WS-LOCAL-VAR REPLACING ALL X'0D25' BY ' '
```

I understand that the INSPECT...REPLACING ALL statement will look through WS-LOCAL-VAR, match the pattern X'0D25' and replace it with a space.

What I don't understand is the purpose of the X outside of '0D25'. All examples of REPLACING ALL that I've found online don't use anything other than a char literal for pattern matching.

How does the X affect which patterns are replaced?

COBOL is running on an EBCDIC machine and the input file is coming from a Windows machine.

Comment: I assume the "X" is telling you that the literal is interpreted as a hex character code.   I don't know what the OP contributes.

Comment: I found a coworker with more COBOL experience and confirmed that you are correct, it matches based on the character with hex code '0D25' (I had written it incorrectly in the question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the Cobol running on a **EBCDIC** machine (Mainframe / AS400) and is the file coming from a **Windows Machine** ???.

Ebcdic has only one end-of-line character **x'25'** as apposed to the 2 (\r, \n) in ascii. **X'0D25'** is the Ebcdic representation of **Windows** *End-of-Line Marker* **\r\n**. In Ebcdic 0D is not a valid character.

Possibly sources of the problem:

- Poor conversion of a Windows Text file when transfered to the mainframe / AS400.
- **Java** (and possibly other modern languages) on Windows. Java on windows supports writing Ebcdic Text files using its standard writers. But on Windows, Java insists on writing **\r\n** even though **\r** is **not a valid EBCDIC character** and you get corrupt files containing x'0D25'.
- If you move a program that hard codes **\r\n** to the mainframe and run it, you will also get x'0d25' in files.

Comment: EBCDIC x'0D' is still the CR character.  It sounds like the file transfer is not properly converting end of lines from the source system, but it is converting the X'0A' LF character to the EBCDIC equivalent X'25'.

Answer (score 4):

The X indicates that the characters in the string are in hexadecimal. In this case, `X"0D"` indicates the return carriage character and `X"25"` the % sign (assuming an ASCII system).

A similar notation is used to indicate national strings (`N"
こんにちは"`) and boolean/bit strings (`B"0101010"`) and their respective hexadecimal equivalents (`NX"01F5A4"` and `BX"2A"`).